# NoClassDefFoundError with Jenkins and Versant

Tags: ant, junit, jenkins, hudson, versant-vod

Currently, I have an application which uses a Versant DB. I can build this application in ant and have an ant-task for unit testing. When I run the testing task from command line, all of the test cases will run correctly. However, when I try to run the ant testing task through Jenkins/Hudson, some of the test cases throw a NoClassDefFoundError looking for one of the Versant files. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing in Jenkins to fix this?

Stack Trace:

```
    [junit] Testcase: warning(junit.framework.TestSuite$1): FAILED
    [junit] Exception in constructor: testGetTransactionWithStubSelector     (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.versant.trans.TransSession
    [junit]     at com.projectName.database.SessionPool.createPooledObject(SessionPool.java:45)
    [junit]     at com.projectName.util.pooling.PoolManager$ReflectivePooledObjectHandler.createPooledObject(PoolManager.java:210)
    [junit]     at com.projectName.util.pooling.PoolManager.init(PoolManager.java:58)
    [junit]     at com.projectName.database.SessionPool.<init>(SessionPool.java:20)
    [junit]     at com.projectName.database.DB.<init>(DB.java:507)
    [junit]     at com.projectName.database.DB.get(DB.java:62)
```

Comment: I am facing same issue